# EditPad Regex replacement

Tags: regex, editpad

I have a bunch of JSON data with entries like this:

```
"FILENAME":"/DownloadFile2.aspx?File=q%3a%5cPeople%5c1026732%5c819%5cLetters%5cAttend1026732160213.pdf",
```

I want to replace all of them with this:

```
"FILENAME":"/DownloadFile2.aspx?File=filename.pdf",
```

How can I use regex to replace them all?

Comment: never used editpad, so I'm not entirely sure, but is `/[^=]+\.pdf/` close to what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the search, put `File=.*\.pdf`
In the replace, put `File=filename.pdf`